# How to set up Loggly on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, loggly

I'd like to set up Loggly to run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but can't find any information on how to do this. Is there any guide anywhere, or some general guidance on how to start?

Comment: Is the http API and option? http://wiki.loggly.com/gettinglogsintologgly I can write a more detailed description if so

Comment: more detailed setup specific to Elastic Beanstalk is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Elastic bean stalk just works of a war file so the Http API making calls directly from you code would work anywhere including elastic beanstalk. Since you don't have access to your machine in beanstalk the syslog api will not work for you.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail you **do** have access to your machine in beanstalk, see how: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it, for papertrailapp.com (which I prefer instead of loggly). In your `/ebextensions` folder ([see more info](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)) you create `logs.config`, where specify:

```
container_commands:
  01-set-correct-hostname:
    command: hostname www.example.com
  02-forward-rsyslog-to-papertrail:
    # https://papertrailapp.com/systems/setup
    command: echo "*.* @logs.papertrailapp.com:55555" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf
  03-enable-remote-logging:
    command: echo -e "\$ModLoad imudp\n\$UDPServerRun 514\n\$ModLoad imtcp\n\$InputTCPServerRun 514\n\$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf
  04-restart-syslog:
    command: service rsyslog restart
```

`55555` should be replaced with the UDP port number provided by papertrailapp.com. Every time after new instance bootstrap this config will be applied. Then, in your `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, SYSLOG
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=local1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.header=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %t %c: %m%n
```

I'm not sure whether it's an optimal solution. Read more about this mechanism in [jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin](http://beanstalk.jcabi.com/example-syslog.html)

Comment: seems like setting the hostname on an EC2 server is not such a good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603351/can-we-set-easy-to-remember-hostnames-for-ec2-instances

Comment: Using this solution on EC2 - I had to change `service rsyslog restart` which didn't work with `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`

Comment: Seems like appending to rsyslog.conf is a bit problematic - multiple deploys to the same set of beanstalk-provisioned servers (a frequent occurrence) would wind up with multiple appends.  Typically, though, /etc/rsyslog.config will have a "$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" at the end - so you can simply introduce your own configuration file using the "files:" portion of your .ebextensions file.  This works whether you are deploying to fresh servers or not.

Comment: +1 to @scolestock 's comment.  I started out with the configuration suggested in the accepted answer, but ended up just creating a new file in /etc/rsyslog.d/.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the installation script from loggly itself. 
The setup below follows the instructions for the legacy setup on https://www.loggly.com/docs/configure-syslog-script/ with minor changes (no confirmation prompts, sudo command replaced since no tty is available)

(edit: updated link, seems to be an outdated solution now in loggly docs)

Place the following script in .ebextensions/loggly.config

Replace TOKEN and ACCOUNT with your own.

```
#
# Install loggly.com on AWS Elastic Beanstalk
# Tested with node.js environment
# Save this file as .ebextensions/loggly.config
# Deploy per normal scripts or aws.push. To help debug the push, ssh & tail /var/log/cfn-init.log
# See Also /var/log/eb-tools.log
#

commands:
  01_loggly_dl:
    command: wget -q -O /tmp/loggly.py https://www.loggly.com/install/configure-syslog.py
  02_loggly_config:
    command: su --session-command="python /tmp/loggly.py setup --auth TOKEN --account ACCOUNT --yes"
```

Comment: Couldn't anyone who compromised Loggly then be able to compromise your servers? Seems insecure to run remote code like this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to loggly support site for using syslogd with loggly:
http://wiki.loggly.com/loggingconfiguration

or using the loggly api with your own app:
http://wiki.loggly.com/apidocumention

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elasticbeanstalk config for Loggly that I've just started using thanks to pointers from this thread and the logging SaaS vendors setup instructions. [[Loggly Config Mgmt](http://loggly.com/support/advanced/configuration-management/), [Papertrail rsyslog](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/advanced-unix-logging-tips#rsyslog_aggregate_log_files) ]

Save the file as loggly.config in the .ebextensions directory and make sure to check the YAML formatting conventions (no tabs, etc).  Substitute your Loggly TCP port number, username, password and domain name into the angle brackets as required.

Note that for AWS ruby versions of elasticbeanstalk, there may be differences in the EC2 /etc/rsyslog setup.  For example, if /etc/rsyslog.d already exists, and there is already an "$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" directive, then command "01-forward-rsyslog-to-loggly:" can be removed.

Deploy per normal scripts or aws.push.  To help debug the push, ssh & tail /var/log/cfn-init.log

```
files:
  "/etc/rsyslog.d/90-loggly.conf" :
    mode: "000664"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # ### begin forwarding rule ###
      # The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
      # rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
      # forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
      # Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
      #
      # An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
      # down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
      $WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
      $ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
      $ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
      $ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
      $ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
      $ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
      *.* @@logs.loggly.com:<yourportnum>   # !!!Loggly supplied port number for each app!!!
      # ### end of the forwarding rule ###
    encoding: plain
  "/tmp/loggly.py" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      import json
      import sys
      import urllib2
      '''
      Auto-authenticate Syslog TCP inputs.
      Usage: python inputs.py -u user -p pass -s subdomain
      '''
      state = None
      params = {}
      for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
         arg = sys.argv[i]
         if state:
             params[state] = arg
             state = None

         if arg == '--username' or arg == '-u':
             state = 'username'

         if arg == '--password' or arg == '-p':
             state = 'password'

         if arg == '--subdomain' or arg == '-s':
             state = 'subdomain'
      url = 'https://%s.loggly.com/api/inputs' % params['subdomain']
      password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
      password_mgr.add_password(None, url, params['username'], params['password'])
      handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
      opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
      opener.open(url)
      urllib2.install_opener(opener)
      inputs = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
      for input in inputs:
         if input['service']['name'] == 'syslogtcp':
             url = 'https://%s.loggly.com/api/inputs/%d/adddevice' % \
                 (params['subdomain'], input['id'])
             response = urllib2.urlopen(url, {}).read()
             print response
    encoding: plain

commands:
  01-forward-rsyslog-to-loggly:
    # http://loggly.com/support/sending-data/logging-from/syslog/rsyslog/cd
    command: test "$(grep -s '90-loggly.conf' /etc/rsyslog.conf)" == "" && echo -e "\n# Include the loggly.conf file\n\$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/90-loggly.conf" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf
  02-restart-syslog:
    command: service rsyslog restart
  03-inform_loggly:
    command: "python /tmp/loggly.py -u <Yourloginname> -p <Yourpassword> -s <Yourdomainname>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, /etc/rsyslog.config will have a "$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" at the end - so you can simply introduce your *own* configuration file using the "files:" portion of your .ebextensions file. This works whether you are deploying to fresh servers or not.

For a ruby production.log, you might have something like this in a .ebextensions/01loggly.config file.  Note this picks up your beanstalk environment name too as a loggly tag.

```
# For docs on eb configs, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
# This set of commands sets up loggly forwarding
files:
   "/etc/rsyslog.d/myapp-loggly.conf" :
      mode: "000664"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
         $template LogglyFormat,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% [yourlogglyid@41058 tag=`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`] %msg%\n"
         *.* @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat

         # One time config
         $ModLoad imfile
         $InputFilePollInterval 10 
         $PrivDropToGroup adm
         $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

         # Add a tag for file events

         # For production.log
         $InputFileName /var/app/support/logs/production.log
         $InputFileTag production-log
         $InputFileStateFile stat-production-log #this must be unique for each file being polled
         $InputFileSeverity info
         $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
         $InputRunFileMonitor
         # Send to Loggly then discard
         if $programname == 'myapp-production-log' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
         if $programname == 'myapp-production-log' then ~

      encoding: plain
commands:
   00-make-work-directory:
      command: mkdir -p /var/spool/rsyslog
   01-restart-syslog:
      command: service rsyslog restart
```

For Tomcat, you might do something like this in a .ebextesions/01logglyg.config file:

```
# For docs on eb configs, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
# This set of commands sets up loggly forwarding
files:
    "/etc/rsyslog.d/mytomcatapp-loggly.conf" :
        mode: "000664"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            $template LogglyFormat,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% [yourlogglygidhere@41058 tag=`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`] %msg%\n"
            *.* @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat

            # One time config
            $ModLoad imfile
            $InputFilePollInterval 10 
            $PrivDropToGroup adm
            $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

            # catalina.log
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.log
            $InputFileTag catalina-log
            $InputFileStateFile stat-catalina-log
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'catalina-log' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'catalina-log' then ~

            # catalina.out
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
            $InputFileTag catalina-out
            $InputFileStateFile stat-catalina-out
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'catalina-out' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'catalina-out' then ~

            # host-manager.log
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/host-manager.log
            $InputFileTag host-manager
            $InputFileStateFile stat-host-manager
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'host-manager' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'host-manager' then ~

            # initd.log
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/initd.log
            $InputFileTag initd
            $InputFileStateFile stat-initd
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'initd' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'initd' then ~

            # localhost.log
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/localhost.log
            $InputFileTag localhost-log
            $InputFileStateFile stat-localhost-log
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'localhost-log' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'localhost-log' then ~

            # manager.log
            $InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/manager.log
            $InputFileTag manager
            $InputFileStateFile stat-manager
            $InputFileSeverity info
            $InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
            $InputRunFileMonitor
            if $programname == 'manager' then @@logs-01.loggly.com:514;LogglyFormat
            if $programname == 'manager' then ~

        encoding: plain
commands:
    00-make-work-directory:
        command: mkdir -p /var/spool/rsyslog
    01-restart-syslog:
        command: service rsyslog restart
```

This config is working for me - though I haven't yet determined how to get multi-line entries coming into a single entry in Loggly yet.

Comment: At the end of the day, this configuration didn't work either.  It doesn't follow catalina.out after the hourly rotation put in place in the amazon linux image.  This works: https://gist.github.com/troy/4710601

Answer (score 1):

I know this is question is fairly old but I found that the answers really didnt answer the question or just plain didnt work correctly when implemented.  I found that this works (file .ebextenstions/02loggly.config):

```
container_commands:
  01-transform-rsyslog.conf:
    command: sed "s/NODE_ENV/$NODE_ENV/g" scripts/22-loggly.conf.temp > scripts/22-loggly.conf
  02-setup-rsyslog.conf:
    command: cp scripts/22-loggly.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/22-loggly.conf
  03-restart:
    command: /sbin/service rsyslog restart
```

the "01-transform-rsyslog.conf" step is optional;  I use that to set a tag by NODE_ENV in the file. "22-loggly.conf.temp" is a modified version of the "22-loggly.conf" file that gets created at "/etc/rsyslog.d/" when you run the linux source setup script (https://www.loggly.com/install/configure-syslog.py).  I just installed it on a ec2 instance and copied the file.

Note I had to prepend '/sbin' to my service command because it was failing for me without it.  Also, this restarts syslog on every deploy, which should be fine.

Now you just have to make sure your app logs to syslog.  For Java it is going to be log4j or similar.  For Node.js (which is what I'm using), rconsole works (https://github.com/tblobaum/rconsole).

Answer (score 0):

None of the things I tried seemed to work, and the loggly documentation is very confusing!
I hope that this will help someone, this is how I got it to work.

Paste the following in .ebextensions/loggly.config

```
files:
  "/etc/rsyslog.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      $ModLoad imfile
      $InputFilePollInterval 10
      $PrivDropToGroup adm

      # Input for FILE.LOG
      $InputFileName /var/app/current/PATH_TO_YOUR_LOG_FILE
      $InputFileTag social_php:
      $InputFileStateFile stat-social_php #this must be unique for each file being polled
      $InputFileSeverity info
      $InputRunFileMonitor

      #Add a tag for events from this file
      $template LogglyFormatsocial_php,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% [TOKEN@41058 tag=\"php_log\"] %msg%\n"

      if $programname == 'social_php' then @@logs.loggly.com:37146;LogglyFormatsocial_php
      if $programname == 'social_php' then ~
      *.*    @@logs.loggly.com:37146


commands:
  01-restart-syslog:
    command: service rsyslog restart
```

- Replace all instances of social_php with the tag that makes sense for your application.
- Replace /var/app/current/PATH_TO_YOUR_LOG_FILE with your log file location

Answer (score 0):

Follow my loggly configuration in elasticbeanstalk. For Linux + log4j

on .ebextensions file configuration

```
container_commands:
  01_configure_sudo_access:
    command: sed -i -- 's/ requiretty/ \!requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
  02_loggy_configure:
    command: sudo python .ebextensions/scripts/loggly_config.py
  03_restore_sudo_access:
    command: sed -i -- 's/ \!requiretty/ requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
```

Loggly script in python for default AMI:

```
import os

rsyslog_path = '/etc/rsyslog.conf'
loggly_file_path = '/etc/rsyslog.d/22-loggly.conf'

class LogglyConfig:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__linux_log()
        self.__config_loggly_for_log4j()

    def __linux_log(self):
        #not installed on this machine
        if not os.path.exists(loggly_file_path):
            os.system('rm -f configure-linux.sh')
            os.system('wget https://www.loggly.com/install/configure-linux.sh')
            os.system('sudo bash configure-linux.sh -a DOMAIN -t TOKEN -u USER -p PASSWORD -s')


    def __config_loggly_for_log4j(self):
        f = open(rsyslog_path,'r')
        file_text = f.read()
        f.close()
        file_text = file_text.replace('#$ModLoad imudp', '$ModLoad imudp')
        file_text = file_text.replace('#$UDPServerRun 514', '$UDPServerRun 514')
        f = open(rsyslog_path,'w')
        f.write(file_text)
        f.close()

        os.system('service rsyslog restart')

LogglyConfig()
```

In log4j.properties on your java project

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG

log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local3
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=java %d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{1}.%M - %m%n
```